# Result of a query from PHP to JavaScript with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I did a query from my database and I want to send the result to my javascript via $.getJSON method. I specify the route where I've my function (showmap):

```
Route::get('showmap', [ 'uses' => 'StorageController@showmap1',
'as' => 'showmap'] );
```

And it will call showmap1():

```
public function showmap1()
{
    //$pictures = Fileentry::all();
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $thumbnails = \DB::table('fileentries')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->select('fileentries.id', 'fileentries.user_id', 'fileentries.filename'
                , 'fileentries.path', 'fileentries.lattitude', 'fileentries.longitude'
                , 'fileentries.created_at', 'fileentries.updated_at')
                ->where('fileentries.user_id', '=', $userId);
        })->get();
    $control = 'map';

    return response()->json($thumbnails);
}
```

The function showmap1() returns:

```
[{"id":12,"user_id":30,"filename":"vlcsnap-2015-06-22-01h45m27s26.png","path":"C:\\Users\\wences\\virtualhost\\World-Picture\\public","lattitude":43.6049606,"longitude":-5.9191785,"created_at":"2015-12-10 22:49:52","updated_at":"2015-12-10 22:49:52"}]
```

My javascript code is this, but seems that it doesn't catch the right data when I want to access to my filename value (for example):

```
$.getJSON('showmap', function(data){                
            $.each(data, function(key,val){
                val.filename; //It doesn't show nothing
            });
        });
```

Comment: console.log(data) before each-loop and see what you've got.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(val.filename)` instead of just `val.filename`?

Comment: Nothing is showed, it is like $.getJSON  is not receiving any data

Comment: @overflow13 check your browser dev panel. Look for request you made.

Comment: @overflow13 if you access the API directly, does it show anything at all? In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ipbuLakIkw1tIQviNhr6?p=preview), I am able to print out `val.filename` in console though. Check your console to see if a request is being made at all.

Comment: @overflow13 is your showmap1 function a controller method?

Comment: Can you check in the browser - to which route does the AJAX request gets sent to? Or maybe can you try to send request to absolute route? like $.getJSON('http://yoursitename.com/showmap' .... 
And then give the result

Comment: @overflow13 Have you tried to print only `val` variable? As it shown in response you got only 1 object.